# How to load address (billing, shipping) by entity_id (address_id)?

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, shipping-address, billing-address

I need to change all addresses (billing, shipping) street attribute. I have only `entity_id` (address_id) from `customer_address_entity_text`.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$addressId = ...your id here...;
$address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($addressId);
$street = 'your street here';
//or if you want to have 2 lines on the street
//$street = array('First line', 'Second line');

if($address->getId()) {
    $address->setStreet($street);
    $address->save();
}
```

Comment: thanks, and how can I get attribute value from this object..For example
I added attribute for customer_address (house_number). And I want to get it from this object (Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($addressId);)
 getHouseNumber() ?

Comment: `$address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($addressId);`. `$houseNumber = $address->getHouseNumber()`